# Hibernate : JsonBlobType not working with Oracle in case of @Audited

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

As suggested in forum -
https://vladmihalcea.com/oracle-json-jpa-hibernate/

I am mapping the oracle blob JSON column with string type in entity using below code -

```
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBlobType.class) })
    @Audited
    @Table(name = "hyperform_common_config")
    @Entity
    public class CommonConfig implements Serializable{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "config_data")
    private String configData;
```

But JsonBlobType is not working in case of @Audited . Error -

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: jsonb-lob, at table: hyperform_common_config_AUD, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(config_data)]
```

Do i need to do any extra configuration for auditing table ?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely by just changing the name of type to "jsonb-lob" it worked -

```
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "jsonb-lob", typeClass = JsonBlobType.class) })
@Audited
@Table(name = "hyperform_common_config")
@Entity
public class CommonConfig implements Serializable{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Type(type = "jsonb-lob")
    @Column(name = "config_data")
    private String configData;
```